# Wordpress post 403 error with content that contain style word

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have fresh install WordPress cms on my shared hosting with the source code from official WordPress site (*https://wordpress.org/download/*), and default configuration. When I create new pages or a new post with when content containing a word "style" for example:

```
this is my post style="flat"
```

it returns page :

> Oops! That page can’t be found.

What's wrong with my wordpress?

Comment: where you saw that warning? provide more details, such as did that pages create, what url you checking and etc.

Comment: i saw that warning in a response page when I post, url is mydomain/wp-admin/post.php